# Proper way to change login process Laravel 5

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

I want to let the user connect to my website with only one different IP per hour. the way i designed this is by making two more columns in DB: storedIP and lastSeen.

Now i don't know how to modify the existing process so that it does the following things on login: Check if the user has been seen less than one hour ago, if yes check his IP and the one in the DB.

What is the clean and proper MVC way to change the existing Login Process to implement this in Laravel 5.3

Thank you guys, Gr3y4nt

Comment: You do not need to change the login process, just add new middleware to check for the ip.

Comment: @Gacek I don't know where to put the middleware...

Comment: Please see this laracast for example: https://laracasts.com/series/laravel-5-fundamentals/episodes/16

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best way would be creating a dedicated middleware for this. You can see comprehensive and easy to understand tutorial [how to do it here](https://laracasts.com/series/laravel-5-fundamentals/episodes/16)

So the whole process would be:

1. Create a migration to add the two columns you need
2. Create a new middleware (and attach it properly - see the video)
3. Write the logic to check if current user can visit your website, or it should be redirected to some info page. Don't forget to update the `storedIP` and `lastSeen` for user.

Tips:

- you can get the logged in user using `Auth::user()`,
- you can get the IP for the current request using `request()->ip()` method,
- you can redirect the user using `redirect('/some/endpoint')` method